# MYSQL - How to find result from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like

I am not good with `mysql` so need to know how to find result from two tables.

Let's say I have two tables:

**Brand table:**

```
Id  Email           Password
--  -----           --------
1   kris@gmail.com  12345678
```

**Facebook table:**

```
Id  Email               Password
--  -----               --------
1   calbares@gmail.com  12345678
```

Now I want to find this email address `calbares@gmail.com` from both table and want to get Email & Password from result.

Any Idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need output from both tables in different rows?

Comment: I want to retrieve email & password.

Comment: @Mr.Happy: It seems you are missing something here as your searching email exists only in facebook table not in brand table...also there is no relation between these 2 tables i.e. both tables are different entities also brand table data don't seems appropriate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM brand_table
union
select * from facebook_table
```

`UNION` will bring distinct records.

If you use `union all`, it will bring duplicates as well.

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM brand_table where email ='calbares@gmail.com'
union all
select * from facebook_table where email ='calbares@gmail.com'
```

Comment: he wants to filter by given email address...I guess you're missing the search filter.

Comment: @ShilpaSoni added that

Comment: Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

To do please try this

```
Select * from Brand where Email = '$email';

UNION ALL

Select * from Facebook where Email = '$email';
```

Answer (score 0):

For more practical use you can use a variable for the email:

```
SET @email='calbares@gmail.com'

SELECT 'Brand' AS Platform, Email, Password
FROM Brand WHERE Email=@email

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Facebook', Email, Password
FROM Facebook WHERE Email=@email
```

Or create a function/procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE find_Passwords(IN emailin varchar(255))
BEGIN
SELECT 'Brand' AS Platform, Email, Password
    FROM Brand WHERE Email=emailin

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Facebook', Email, Password
    FROM Facebook WHERE Email=emailin
END
```

That you can call with:

```
CALL find_Passwords('calbares@gmail.com')
```

Comment: what is the need of creating a procedure? and why should he be creating variables? that's not something like "For more practical use ", that is all on what you need and what are the requirements :)/.

Comment: So that it can be used multiple times for different emails easily. Just extrapolating on why this query may be required.

Comment: I hope he will be using it in some application, he would for sure pass the params. That is all based on assumptions so far :)

Answer (score 0):

The emailaddress is the same in both tables?

If yes, use this command:

```
"SELECT brand.password AS brand_pw, facebbok.password AS fb_password FROM brand JOIN facebook ON facebook.email = 'calbares@gmail.com' WHERE brand.email = 'calbares@gmail.com'"
```

As result you shoul get two values: brand_pw and fb_password. Because you know the email, there is no need to collect it from the table.

But if you also want to get the email, simply add the following right after SELECT: brand.email AS brand_mail, facebook.email AS fb_email

So the full command should look like this:

```
"SELECT brand.password AS brand_pw, brand.email AS brand_mail, facebook.email AS fb_email, facebbok.password AS fb_password FROM brand JOIN facebook ON facebook.email = 'calbares@gmail.com' WHERE brand.email = 'calbares@gmail.com'"
```

So you get 4 values back.